# How to display success or failer message after WordPress form submited?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a form in WordPress Plugin using general HTML tags. I just tested with echo for text box submitted value and it is working fine. I need to redirect or display success / failure message in same page after submitting form. How to display success or failure message after form submitted?

Comment: What did you try? Why you don't use a plugin for creating forms? e.g. formidable.. or use google -> 'Wordpress form ajax plugin'.

Comment: actually I am developing plugin and once action is completed, need to show success or failure message.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txt">Enter Text</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt1" name="txt1" value="" placeholder="Enter your text..." />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])) {     
        $txt1 = trim($_POST['txt1']);
        $count=0;
        if(empty($txt1)) {
            echo '<div class="error">Please enter your text.</div>';
        } else {
            header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php");
            $count=1;
            if($count=1)
    { 
                echo  '<label for="msg">Succes Message</label>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is what follows:

```
// After form save function ends do:
wp_redirect($your_post_url . '&saved=1');
exit;

// Wherever you need the html do:
if (isset($_GET['saved'])) echo 
  '<div class="updated">
    <p>' . __('Success! Values have been saved.') . '</p>
  </div>';
```